# finding peak intervals from column data

Tags: c#, math

I have some integers values like this:

2 4 **6** 4 2 4 **8** 4 2 3 **7** 4 2

I need to find the peaks - which are the points of my array where the values stop increasing. In above example, there are three peaks - `6, 8, 7`

How can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: How do you define a peak?

Comment: @st4hoo Should be a point where values start decreasing I guess.

Comment: like i have described in question, 6 is the peak then 4,2,4 are smaller and then again 8 is peak. so in that way if you try to visualize it as a bar chart then i want to consider the interval between two bars which are peak values. i.e between 6 and 8 , 8 and 7 in that manner.

Comment: interval is just a number of values that comes between two peaks. interval is how many numbers are there between 6 and 8. So there are 3 numbers between 6 and 8 so interval is 3.

Comment: What if there will be sequence like this: 1 2 3 2 4 5 4 3 2 1. Is first occurence of 3 also a peak? What if: 1 2 3 4 4 4 3 2 1 ? Do we have three peaks or just one in such case?

Comment: for 1 2 3 2 4 5 4 3 2 1 => 3 and 5 will be the peak values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is it you're trying to get, but here's what I've got:

```
public List<Tuple<int, int>> GetPeaks(int[] values)
{
    List<Tuple<int, int>> results = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    List<int> curInterval = new List<int>();

    bool decreasing = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (curInterval.Count > 0)
        {
            if (values[i] < curInterval.Last() && !decreasing)
            {
                results.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i - 1, curInterval.Last()));
                curInterval.Clear();
                decreasing = true;
            }
            else if (values[i] >= curInterval.Last() && decreasing)
            {
                decreasing = false;
            }
        }
        curInterval.Add(values[i]);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Seem to work [here](http://rextester.com/IML43119) (updated after edits). The method will return Tuples containing (peakPosition, peakValue). The code is pretty self explanatory, and I'm pretty sure better can be done.

Comment: It was my pleasure :p

Comment: i tried it with the 93
113
113
75
50
94
127
118
63
62
111
129
105
49
77
124
132
92
48
98
137
132
78
60
116
145
124
65
78
129
150
113
58
97
146
151
94
62
113
157
143
73
73
134
162
129
63
93
148
158
112
63
114
160
152
90
73
132
166
144
73
89
150
167
126
67
110
161
164
105
69
128
168
155
82
89
146
170
137
74
107
160
171
121
72
123
171
168
105
82
144
173
155
82
100
160
176
139
78
120
168
172
114
78
136
173
162
97
95
157
182
146
79
110
162
176
126
75
129
177
167
103
85
147
175
152
86
103
158
174
132
75
117
166
170
112
74
134
172
155
84
92
151
171
140
74
105
160 but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Yeah, just a little logical flaw here, one sec'. EDIT: done, try it now

Comment: yes now it seems to give the expected results. else if (curInterval.Count > 0 && values[i] >= curInterval.Last() && decreasing)
                {
                    decreasing = false;
                }   need to check the count > 0 otherwise will throw an error. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: The issue was that my loop automatically said that the values weren't decreasing anymore after the first one checked in every new interval. Changed the "else" to a "else if" with what's needed to avoid that.

Comment: The count > 0 is already checked, I moved it on the upper block while I was at it :p